# Why won't amp-img files work as expected in php include files?

Tags: php, amp-html

I have the following in one of my include files:

```
<amp-img width="289" height="53" layout="fixed" src="img/prem-logo-new.svg" alt="Premier Appliance Care logo"></amp-img>
```

The above renders as expected but I want my logo to be responsive like so, it doesn't display at all ...

```
<amp-img width="289" height="53" layout="responsive" src="img/prem-logo-new.svg" alt="Premier Appliance Care logo"></amp-img>
```

This renders fine if it isn't an include file. `<amp-img width="289" height="53" layout="responsive" src="img/prem-logo-new.svg" alt="Premier Appliance Care logo"></amp-img>`

I have validated the above successfully. Any suggestions?

Comment: might be variable issue, share your php code also

Comment: There are no variables...

Comment: I have fixed this. The issue was related to my layout and the CSS. Sorry for posting! When I removed my the link to my css file it displayed as expected.